# A question regarding the all pair shortest paths in weighted planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs

What is the time complexity of the fastest known algorithm for the all-pair shortest paths in planar graphs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in quadratic time using the linear-time single-source shortest path algorithm by [Henzinger et al.](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs267/papers/planar-sssp.pdf)

Comment: Thank you.I would have voted you up if i could.